# After changing sublayout code, do I need to do a Sitecore publish?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I change my code on my sublayout.  What I should do to see my changes modified on the sublayout output ? Do I have to smart publish ?

What is the difference betwen smart publish and incremental publish.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't change Sitecore items, you don't have to publish. Just recompile your code.

And read [this article](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/contentreference-a4.pdf) (paragraph 3.2 Publishing types) to get the idea of various publishing types and differences between those.